# jQuery: Select global checkbox when all its options have been selected

Tags: jquery

I've seen several 'check all' solutions here but none that works the other way around: select the global checkbox when all its options have been selected.

I have a list of groups. Each group has 4 items and an 'Unsubscribe from all' option at the bottom.

So far I've been able to handle the "check all" options, but I'm struggling with being able to check a group's 'Unsubscribe from all' option, when all unsubscribe options have been selected.

Here's a ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/pYcQY/4/)*** (old now) of what I have so far. At the bottom is the piece of code I have for this, but of course, it doesn't work.

The other  functionalities work fine except, this one is the one I need a hand with.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT -** *Adding link to fiddle since the solution is buried in the comments below. Thanks to **j08691** for the script.*

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/pYcQY/19/)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this chunk of code:

```
$(".opt-out input:radio").click(function() {
    if($(this).parents('table').find(".opt-out input:checked").length==4)$(this).parents('table').find(".unsubs-chkbx-group").attr('checked','checked');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pYcQY/6/)**

Comment: j08691, is there a way to make the amount 'generic' in case they need to add more than 4 options and have the code still work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, instead of comparing it to 4, compare it to the length of the number of checkboxes. So instead of `if($(this).parents('table').find(".opt-out input:checked").length==4)` use `if($(this).parents('table').find(".opt-out input:checked").length==$(this).parents('table').find(".opt-out input").length)`

Comment: j08691, JSLint validator is telling me there's a problem at line 30 character 74: *Expected '{' and instead saw '$'.* Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I think I see what you mean. That's kind of a bogus warning. It's generated because the code for the if condition isn't enclosed in `{}`. You can wrap it in the brackets if you want but since it's a single line it's perfectly valid.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks man, really appreciate your help. Wish you could accept both answers :p

Comment: No problem. thecodeparadox has more points than me so I'm sure he won't mind if you accept my answer :P

Comment: I was able to make everything work, here's the final working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/pYcQY/19/ - Thanks again.

Comment: I was just kidding about shifting the accepted answer BTW. If thecodeparadox gave you a better answer then by all means, pick his answer.

Comment: Agree. However, although I planned to use his answer, I ran into callback issues. So I tried it with yours and I was able to add the necessary callbacks and adaptations. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/pYcQY/19/

Answer (score 1):

You need a [*`change()`*](http://api.jquery.com/change) event to `radio` button like below:

```
$('.opt-out input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var table = $(this).closest('table'),
        checkedBoxes = table.find('.opt-out input[type=radio]:checked').length,
        total = table.find('.opt-out input[type=radio]').length;
        table
           .find('input[type=checkbox].unsubs-chkbx-group')
           .attr('checked', checkedBoxes === total);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pYcQY/11/)**

### Note

`:radio` selector is ***[deprecated is jQuery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)***.

Comment: thecodeparadox, I like your code because I can add/substract options and still works. However, there's a small problem: If you select one Subscribe option and all the rest of the Unsubscribe ones, the 'Unsubscribe from all' option gets selected.

Comment: @Ricardo I think problem solved. check the new demo and answer

Comment: thecodeparadox, it works great! I will update `input:radio` to `input[type=radio]`. Thanks!

Comment: thecodeparadox, I'm looking into maybe using your suggested code, and I need to add a callback to add a class `.active` to the label of the 'Unsubscribe from all' option, but what I have so far immediately adds the class as soon as one of the options is selected. Any idea where I need to place this callback? Here's my modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/pYcQY/13/ - Thanks!